# SharePoint: Xml code for OWA inbox web part to provision in onet.xml?

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to find the xml code for the owa inbox web part, i can only find the code for the owa calender which is:

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="MiddleRightZone" WebPartOrder="1">
<![CDATA[
<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2"> 
<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly> 
<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.OWACalendarPart</TypeName> 
<Title>$Resources:spscore,PersonalSiteOnet_WebPart_Calendar</Title> 
<Description>$Resources:spscore,PersonalSiteOnet_WebPart_Calendar_Description</Description<PartOrder>1</PartOrder> 
<FrameType>Default</FrameType> 
<AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize> 
<AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove> 
<IsVisible>true</IsVisible>
<DetailLink>https://<exchange server address>/owa/</DetailLink>
<OWAServerAddressRoot xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:owapart">https://<exchange server address>/owa/</OWAServerAddressRoot>
</WebPart>
]]>
</AllUsersWebPart>
```

now i'm trying to find the correct code for getting the title and description, i've tried:

```
<Title>$Resources:spscore,PersonalSiteOnet_WebPart_Inbox</Title>
```

Mailbox, Mail, Email.. etc. but can't seem to find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Owa webparts are OOTB available right? Can't you just lookup the `dwp` file in the **12 hive** and check the correct title?

Also adding the webpart to the page and exporting it also gives you a `dwp` file with information..

Comment: Thank you! Indeed the dwp file in the hive contained the correct syntax.

Exporting the webpart though only contained the title and desc. in pure text as it had already been procecced by the server.

Comment: exporting indeed only contains the processed info. It does however give you an assembly and stuff, so not completely useless... but im glad your issue is solved :)